# Is "I'm fine to [verb]" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality

For example, I found myself saying "I'm fine to wait" but realized it seems wrong. "I'm fine with waiting" strikes me as the correct alternative. In general "fine with" seems right and "fine to" seems wrong.

Am I correct here? Thanks for any explanations!

(Apologies, I've never studied grammar formally and am not sure where to look to answer my own question.)

Comment: I think "I'm fine waiting." works just as well, leaving out "with".

Answer (score 11):

The syntax of "I'm fine to wait" is the same as that of "I'm happy to wait," which is obviously correct; in the terminology of Huddleston & Pullum (2002), *happy* is an adjective taking an infinitival complement. *Fine* isn't on H&P's list of adjectives that allow this construction (p. 1258). But they were writing in 2002, and [as Ngram shows](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%27m+fine+to&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019&smoothing=3) using *fine* in this way has suddenly become popular within the past couple of decades.

This may explain your confusion: this usage of *fine* makes perfect grammatical sense, but it only emerged relatively recently; presumably some speakers will find it more acceptable than others.

Comment: But doesn't _fine_ describe the situation rather than the speaker? As in _That's fine by me._ Or maybe I'm behind the times and the usage is changing.

Comment: @KateBunting that's a different usage. The OP is asking specifically about the case where _fine_ is followed by a verb in its infinitive form.

Comment: @terdon - Which I, as an older BrE speaker, find unidiomatic.

Comment: As do I, it feels clumsy. I would always add something (e.g. _I'm fine just waiting here_ or whatever). Alphabet is quite right though and  can indeed find many examples [in actual books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22i%20%27m%20fine%20to%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2019,cd_max:2019&lr=lang_en).

Comment: @KateBunting You speak older  British English?

Comment: @Araucaria-Him - If I had meant that, I would have said 'a speaker of older British English'!

Comment: @KateBunting Oh, I see. I must have misunderstood! I hope that doesn't mean you're flagging?

Comment: @KateBunting Sorry, couldn't avoid the pun.

Comment: Some people consider "I'm fine" (meaning "I'm OK" or "I'm well") to be unacceptable, so "I'm fine to" might fall in the same category.